# Which one is better? xAct or Sagemanifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am just starting to learn a language for computing tensor calculus or differential geometrical computations. So i am looking for a list of pros and cons of xact in mathematica and on the other hand Sagemanifolds in phyton.

Comment: Could you provide python part summary? Otherwise maybe it is better to move it to stack overflow? p.s. you can try on community.wolfram.com